# How to avoid showing hint text in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on simple login form.
I have two text fields as user name and password.

user name text field have hint as "user name".

password text field have hint as "password".

I want to hide hint text while clicking inside textbox.

here i faced two problems,

1. if i click inside user name text box the hint text is hiding. but when i press ctrl+z then again the hint appearing and able to edit by pressing keyboard arrow keys.
2. second one is the password text field type is password. so it is not showing hint text as "password".

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>login</title>
<script>
function ForUserName()
{
    if(document.getElementById('username').value == "user name")
    {
       document.getElementById('username').value='';
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('username').value == '')
    {
       document.getElementById('username').value='user name';
    }
}

function ForPassword()
{
    if(document.getElementById('password').value == "password")
    {
       document.getElementById('password').value='';
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('password').value == '')
    {
       document.getElementById('password').value='password';
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="username" value="user name" onclick="ForUserName();" onblur="ForUserName();">
<input type="password" id="password" value="password" onclick="ForPassword();" onblur="ForPassword();">

</body>
</html>
```

can any one please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a HTML5 attribute that does that called `placeholder`. So you just do:

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="user name">
```

And for the backward compatibility (older browsers) you just follow this [tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text).

Comment: Read my whole answer. I provided you a tutorial for backwards compatibility which will work in **any** browser

Comment: yes.. my first problem solved.thank you. can you please give me a solution for password field

Comment: Well there shouldn't really be a placeholder for password since password is of type `password` so the user might think his password was auto entered.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `placeholder`. you dont need any JavaScript for that and it is supported by all latest browsers. [jsfiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjR5m/)

```
 <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="user name" onclick="ForUserName();" onkeyup="ForUserName();">
```

Comment: @suresh.g yes. you can get many placeholder plugin (mostly jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

You could use *HTML5′s placeholder Attribute*

```
<input type="text" id="username"  placeholder="user name">
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
```

For supporting old browsers:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="user name"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'user name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'user name';}">
<input type="password" id="password" value="password" onfocus="if (this.value == 'password') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}">
```